# Error running Kafka on Windows 10: The system cannot execute the specified program

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to run Kafka locally on Windows 10. I've got Zookeeper installed and running. I've downloaded the binary file for kafka_2.13-3.4.0. I've saved kafka files in location "C:\Temp\kafka_2.13-3.4.0", and configured the Environment variables(in C drive path without spaces):
User variables-
JAVA_HOME - "C:\Temp\Java\jdk-20",
JRE_HOME - "C:\Temp\Java\JRE8",
Path - "C:\Temp\Java\jdk-20\bin","C:\Temp\Java\JRE8\bin".

System variables-
Path - Configured same as above.

I've also updated the server.properties file to modify log.dirs="C:/Temp/kafka_2.13-3.4.0/data/kafka" (valid path created).

I have Zookeeper running fine after executing "bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat C:\Temp\kafka_2.13-3.4.0\config\zookeeper.properties"(zookeeper.properties already updated with valid dataDir), but when I am trying to run Kafka, I am getting the error "The system cannot execute the specified program."

bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat C:\Temp\kafka_2.13-3.4.0\config\server.properties

Please Help.

Ran kafka-server-start.bat after running Zookeeper

Comment: Kafka isn't tested on Windows. Use WSL2 or Docker, or a VM